# Is it possible to limit a conversation duration in OCS?

Tags: c#, sdk, ocs, office-communicator, ucma2.0

I am trying to develop an application which starts conversation between 2 random users within the company. We are using OCS 2007 R2.

I am creating this conversation via UCMA 2.0 with the below code, but I am not sure if there is a way to limit the created conversation duration with 3 minutes. So

1. **Is there any way to accomplish this task via UCMA 2.0?**
2. **What is other options rather than cancelling the conversation via the same bot which creates this conversation in 3 minute?**
3. **Is there any way to customize Conversation screen in Office Communicator? So I could show a counter which shows the left duration in conversation?**(Like: 20 second left)

Thanks anyway.

```
UserEndpointSettings userEndpointSettings = new UserEndpointSettings(_userURI, _userServer);
userEndpointSettings.Credential = _credential;
_userEndpoint = new UserEndpoint(_collabPlatform, userEndpointSettings);
_userEndpoint.BeginEstablish(EndEndpointEstablish, _userEndpoint);

ConversationSettings convSettings = new ConversationSettings();
convSettings.Priority = _conversationPriority.Normal;
convSettings.Subject = "Your trip plan";

Conversation conversation = new Conversation(_userEndpoint, convSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off opening a ticket with MS.

Comment: Actually I wanted the learn the limits of UCMA and other API's. Do you think it is necessary for this application to open a ticket?